# How to print variable dtype only object in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I am very new to use Python. I would like to print the variables that are 'object' dtype. Can you please help me with the syntax. I tried the below code

```
df.info()
```

but it gives the list of all variables with the dtypes float and int. I just want to print object dtype variables only.

For example: When I used `df.info()` I got the below results. but I dont want the other dtypes except object.

````
RangeIndex: 1460 entries, 0 to 1459
Data columns (total 81 columns):
Id               1460 non-null int64
MS               1460 non-null int64
MSZ              1460 non-null object
Lo               1201 non-null float64
LA               1460 non-null int64
St               1460 non-null object
Al               91 non-null object ```
````

Comment: `df.select_dtypes('O')` ? Docs [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html)

Comment: Hello Anky_91, I know this code. But my question is different. Please go through the question. I used the same code ```df.select_dtypes(include=['object'])```.

Comment: Hello nakE, I want to print the variables from the dataframe that are only object dtype.

Comment: does `df.select_dtypes('O').info()` prints what you need? Otherwise, can you explain why it is not what you need? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to print the variables from the dataframe that are only object dtype

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Id': [1], 'Name': ['xyz'], 'Weight': [12.34], 'Date': pd.to_datetime('2020-01-01'), '?': None})

df.select_dtypes('O').columns.to_list()
#['Name', '?']
```

Or, if you want to print the names one per line:

```
print(*df.select_dtypes('O').columns.to_list(), sep='\n')
#Name
#?
```